# Apply Spring Data's ReactiveCrudRepository to Redis

Tags: reactive, spring-data-redis

I'm playing with Spring Boot 2 with `webflux`. I'm trying to use `ReactiveSortingRepository` to simplify redis ops.

```
public interface DataProfileRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<DataProfileDTO, String> {
}
```

Simply use this interface

```
Mono<DataProfileDTO> tmp = this.dataProfileRepository.findById(id);
```

exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.tradeshift.dgps.dto.DataProfileDTO] to type [reactor.core.publisher.Mono<?>]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrapperConverters.toWrapper(ReactiveWrapperConverters.java:197) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:587) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
```

is thrown.

The behavior of this repository didn't match reactor, I can see in the debug mode, an actual `DataProfileDTO` was fetched from redis. And failed when trying to:

```
GENERIC_CONVERSION_SERVICE.convert(reactiveObject, targetWrapperType);
```

in `ReactiveWrapperConverters.toWrapper`

I went googling, it seems Spring Data Redis 2.0 doesn't mention reactive repository support. I'm wondering if anything I did wrong in my code or Spring Data Redis 2.0 just doesn't support ReactiveCrudRepository yet.

Comment: Did you manage to get it figured out?

Comment: Spring Data Redis 2.3.8.RELEASE does not support Reactive Repositories. Exception message while bean creation is "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by Redis. Offending repository is xx.xxxx.xxxx.XRepository!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Spring's documentation for [Reactive Redis Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:reactive), the highest level of abstraction to interface with Redis with reactive support is [`ReactiveRedisTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisTemplate.html). The [`ReactiveRedisConnection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/ReactiveRedisConnection.html) is lower abstraction that works with binary values (ByteBuffer) as input and output.

There's no mention of support of reactive repositories.
You can also consult the official reactive examples in the [spring-data github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/redis/reactive).

In order for all this to work, you need to have reactive support in the driver you're using - currently that would be [lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core).

Although not ideal, an alternative is [`Flux.fromIterable()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-). You can use blocking repository and handle the result in reactive way.

```
public interface DataProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<DataProfileDTO, String> {
}
```

And wrap it:

```
Flux.fromIterable(dataProfileRepository.findById(id)), DataProfileDTO.class))
```